# How to move label in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**I want to move label little bit up when clicked on input field with JavaScript or CSS if possible **

This is HTML Part

```
<div className="inputbox">
        <div className="label">
           <img src={icon} alt="" width={width} height={height} />
           <label htmlFor={type}>{labelText}</label>
        </div>
        <input type={type} name={type} className="authInput" required />
     </div>
```

**CSS I tried**

```
.inputbox input:focus ~ .label,
.inputbox input:valid ~ .label{
   position: absolute;
   top: -18px;
   left: 0;
}
```

[image: Form Image]

Comment: `input:focus ~ .label` looks for html structure  that matches : `<input> <tag class="label">` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator . Your HTML requires javascript here  :( --/--  CSS will not be able to do this here.

Comment: Thank you , i got the point 

Comment: you can update the question (& title) to find how to do it in reactjs/javascript and remove the css tag  ;) then the question is not a duplicate anymore and can be reopen, else delete it and ask another question about react only ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your selector does not match your html structure. You are matching every label class which is preceded by an input field. The `~` selector works only from left to right, not the other way around, which would be better in your case.

You can now either switch around the `input` and `div` field or use *Javascript* to apply styles when the element is focused.

Answer (score -2):

```
.inputbox input:focus + .label,
.inputbox input:valid + .label{
  position: absolute;
   top: -18px;
   left: 0;
}
```

**I changed ~ sign to + sign and it is working now**

[image: Result]

Comment: There is no way this is working with the markup you provided in the question.

Comment: This is working perfectly you better learn css again :(

Comment: A more likely situation is that you need to learn what a [mcve] is.